# How do I grab the value of a radio button in jQuery and set the value of a text element?

Tags: jquery, forms, text

How can I write the jQuery code needed in order to do the following?

When the user clicks on any radio button, it should:
get the id of the radio button selected and store that id value in a variable you create
Then you need to target the top paragraph on the page (the one with the id of $showPrice) to change the text to read: $X.XX month
Show the correct value depending on what was selected.

I have tried using $(this).val() in various places, but I am still clueless in how to do this.

Can anyone give me some suggestions on how to help me with this question?

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated!

Sean

HTML

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-
    1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <script>

    var idStored = 

    $("input[type=radio][name=product]:checked" ).val();

    </script>

    <body>
    <p id="showPrice">Make a selection:</p>
    <p>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="product" value="Digital Access Only" 
    id="$5.00 month">
      Digital Access Only

    </label><br>


    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="product" value="Sunday Delivery Only" 
    id="$5.60 month">
      Sunday Delivery Only
    </label><br>

    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="product" value="Friday - Sunday Delivery" 
    id="$7.00 month">
      Friday - Sunday Delivery
    </label><br>

    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="product" value="Full Access" id="$10.50 
    month">
      Full Access
    </label>
    </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        var val = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#showPrice').text(val);
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow, works great! Thanks for answering so quickly and so accurately.